# queing multiple file upload in php

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I'm sorry if this has been asked I can't find the correct keywords to look in google. So I decided to ask here in SO.

right now, I have an upload function that is built in laravel where it can upload to 20 images at a time, but client would like to it to be 50 images at a time, so I'm thinking I can't edit php.ini everytime the client wants to increase the maximum uploads at the same time cause it might break the server.

is it possible in php to upload in queue like 10 images for this second next second is 10 images again until the upload are all done so the server won't break.

```
foreach ($request->file('image') as $key => $file) 
        {
            $filename = md5(time() . uniqid()) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $imagesize = getimagesize($file);

            if( ($imagesize[0] == 533 && $imagesize[1] == 800) == false && 
                ($imagesize[0] == 800 && $imagesize[1] == 533) == false 
              ) {
                $error++;
                continue;
            }

            $file->move('uploads', $filename);

            $data['image'] = url('uploads/' . $filename);

            $order_id = 1;

            $count = PropertyImages::where('property_id', $id)->count();

            if( $count > 23 )
            {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'Images must not exceed 24']);
            }

            $image = PropertyImages::where('property_id', $id)->orderBy('order_id', 'DESC')->first();

            if( $image )
            {
                $order_id = $image->order_id + 1;
            }

            $item = PropertyImages::create([
                'property_id' => $id,
                'filename' => $filename,
                'order_id' => $order_id
            ]);

            $items[$key]['id'] = $item->id;
            $items[$key]['filename'] = url('uploads/' . $item->filename);

       }
```

Comment: If I get it right, yes, I bet you can set a counter variable (i.e. `$count = 1;`) before the `foreach` loop and do `if($count % 10 == 0){ sleep(1); } $count++;` just before the end of your `foreach` loop. That will stop the process for a second after each set of 10 uploads, then retake the loop. But I'm not sure if this won't trigger the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what setup you are using for uploading images, so I assume that you have a plain simple form with 20 file input fields.

PHP.ini limits the size of request (e.g. post_max_size=20M will limit your request to 20MB or max_input_vars = 20 will limit variables in request to 20) so it all depends upon what limit you are using in your PHP.ini

So if you have limited max_input_vars = 20 and you are able to send 20 images in single post request, for sending 50 images to server will need 3 requests (max 20 images per request and 10 for last)

Now if you are using simple plain form then it can't do the job because with click on submit button you will be able to submit your form only once. For this you will have to submit your form using javascript (or jQuery). Using JS you will be able to submit images in multiple AJAX requests.

Here is a jQuery plugin that can do the job very efficiently
https://github.com/zimt28/laravel-jquery-file-upload

Little help for using it with Laravel
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/jquery-file-upload-with-laravel

Happy Coding!!